# What permission needed for php?

Tags: php, postfix-mta

I would like to check postfix active queue. I php script I use

```
$active = shell_exec('/bin/ls -1 /var/spool/postfix/active | /usr/bin/wc -l');
```

But in log I see

```
/bin/ls: cannot open directory /var/spool/postfix/active: Permission denied
```

What group I need to add php or postfix to avoid this error ?

Comment: Have you tried `0777`? If even that doesn't work, it's your configuration.

Comment: apache need read access to that directory.

Comment: @Cole it is bad practice to give 777 for a system folder just for read some file/logs by php/web server. Their are other solutions like setup readable alternative path or add web user to group.

Comment: @kuldeep I never suggested it was good practice. I'm just saying that if 0777 doesn't fix it, then your configuration is messed up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically, the postfix mail queues are mode 0700, so only postfix can directly read/write the queue directories. It looks like what you're trying to do is get a count of items in the **active** queue. You can sort of do this using the [`mailq`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/mailq.postfix) (or `postqueue -p`) command, which you should be able to run as apache. It lists all the queue items for all of the queues, but like the man page says, ones in the **active** queue has a `*` after the queue ID. So you can try replacing your `ls -l` command with:

```
$active = shell_exec('/usr/sbin/postqueue -p | grep '^[A-F0-9]*\*' | wc -l');
```